# How to use hashing to compare many files from two directories and find which are identical?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I have a dataset that I'm migrating from an online drive to an on-site one. I'm also doing data management, so as I go I'm reorganizing and renaming the files to fit with our new standard (at this time not editing any data). This is all GIS data, which is referenced in various projects people have on this drive and work computers. Moving or updating these will end up breaking the source on basically all of the files, so I need to find a way to replace them.

I already figured out how to replace the source file paths, but it requires that I know what the old and new filepaths are. The only other way I can think to do this is by hand copying the old and new ones or matching them up as I go, which is... not ideal. I've seen a lot of stuff about comparing single files to each other but I can't for the life of me find anything about comparing two folders of files or something of that nature. This has probably been answered elsewhere but I couldn't find it, so please point me to an answer if you already know of one on here.

Additional info: the total amount of data we have is ~150 gb but probably 1/3 doesn't need messed with and could be excluded since its things like images and backlogs of things that will most likely never be used again and deleted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a cryptographic hash, the hash will uniquely identify a file by its contents.  You can create a dictionary of hashes to file paths on both the old files and new files, then match them together to create a mapping from old to new.  There are a lot of good choices of hash algorithm in the [`hashlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).

```
import hashlib
import glob

old_files = dict()
for fn in glob.glob(old_path, recursive=True):
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        hash = hashlib.md5(f.read())
        old_files[hash.digest()] = fn
new_files = dict()
for fn in glob.glob(new_path, recursive=True):
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        hash = hashlib.md5(f.read())
        new_files[hash.digest()] = fn
mapping = { val: new_files[key] for key,val in old_files.items() if key in new_files }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use rsync. It does all this file syncing for you between two directories.

rsync is often used for remote copying, but you can use it for local copy as well.

Alternatively, if you need to do this often, just check all your files into Git and then copying to another machine or another directory is just a git pull/push. You can do this without a Git server as Git is a distributed VCS. Git can detect renames and files with duplicate content, so that kind of operation would be pretty quick.